# Animated sprites using Awe6 game framework

Tags: haxe, nme

I am looking for a way to have an animated character in my game. I would like to have a running animation loop when he is running, a jump animation when he jumps etc.

Does the awe6 framework provide anything like this? Maybe using spritesheets, or separate images for each frame.

If I have to use my own system, are there any popular libraries that can help do this, and that work well with awe6? And how would I use it with the framework?

Answer (score 0):

awe6 is not something that works out of the box but rather an architecture for you to build on. It is not designed to fill your requirements without work from you and requires you to have at least a good understanding to integrate another framework/target runtime for what you want. They do have a wiki however you can start with http://code.google.com/p/awe6/wiki/QuickStart

There are many popular frameworks out there that have a lower barrier to entry, such as haxepunk.com, haxeflixel.com, https://github.com/aduros/flambe they all have their own strengths/weaknesses etc for you to decide on and can all easily complete your requests.